# How to implement prefix match for keys in redis?

Tags: redis, node-redis

I have the following set of key value pairs in Redis

```
"690-product-Qwaf@#45" :"mens-clothing/shirts"
"690-product-Ywsg##67" :"womens-clothing/shirts"
"690-product-Wsrf@%59" : "boys-clothing/sweaters"
"690-brand-P2af@#45" : "Puma"
"690-brand-Z3af&#35" : "Free People"
"690-brand-Q4af%#49" : "True Religion"
```

I need to fetch only the keys starting with "690-brand-" from the above set. How can I achive the same in redis?.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can **scan** the keys by using the `SCAN` command of redis. See documentation http://redis.io/commands/scan

Example

`SCAN 0 MATCH "690-brand-*"`

for a node.js example see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37405810/6265117

You can also use `KEYS` command if you are working on a development environment or debugging something and database is not very large.
Link - http://redis.io/commands/keys

**NOTE**: `KEYS` is not recommended for production environments.